# How to access a python script using Spring framework?

Tags: python, spring

guys I am currently working on a project where I have to integrate a web based application with machine learning.

What the web page does is basically ask the user a couple of questions, whatever the user answers is stored in a Hashmap with question id and question answer.

I have to send this set of answers to a learning algorithm which has been implemented using python.The learning algorithm will return a set of confidence values for the answers and I have to simply display them on the results web-page.

I am using the Spring frame-work to develop the web-app.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is not a code writing service. Please take some time to read [ask] and update your question to include a [mcve] showing what you have tried and the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jython library

You can invoke and write python script directly using java code and execute it

Here is official link for documentation:

http://www.jython.org/devguide/

Here is link for maven central dependency:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.python/jython

Comment: So, I wil have to write the entire machine learning code in spring using jython to used it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a REST API around the python ML code and return a JSON which can then be easily parsed in spring.